# java Jtable JscrollPane the JTable displaying at full screen height

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a problem with the JTable and scrollbars i tried several things now it's ok only if the frame is at full screen height see the screenshots below :

[image]

[image: full height]

What i tried to achieve this :

```
 Dimension dim = new Dimension(400,350);
    tableProd.setSize(dim);
    tableProd.setPreferredSize(dim);
    tableProd.setMinimumSize(dim);
    tableProd.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    tableProd.setModel(modeleDatas);
    tableProd.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(dim);

    JScrollPane scrollTab=new JScrollPane(tableProd);    
    scrollTab.setPreferredSize(dim);

    panelProd.add(scrollTab, gbc);
```

even extends JTable with this JSTable :

```
public class JSTable extends JTable {

/**
 * Returns false to indicate that horizontal scrollbars are required
 * to display the table while honoring perferred column widths. Returns
 * true if the table can be displayed in viewport without horizontal
 * scrollbars.
 * 
 * @return true if an auto-resizing mode is enabled 
 *   and the viewport width is larger than the table's 
 *   preferred size, otherwise return false.
 * @see Scrollable#getScrollableTracksViewportWidth
 */
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
if (autoResizeMode != AUTO_RESIZE_OFF) {
    if (getParent() instanceof JViewport) {
    return (((JViewport)getParent()).getWidth() > getPreferredSize().width);
    }
} 
return false;
}
```

}

UI code :

```
 public class Fenetre extends JFrame {
```

private JPanel panels = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

```
    public Fenetre(){

    this.setTitle("Gestion Station Phone");
    this.setSize(900, 800);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initMenu();
    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

     GridBagConstraints gbcPage = new GridBagConstraints();
    cardBD.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    titrePage.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,22));
    gbcPage.gridx=0;
    gbcPage.gridy=0;
    gbcPage.gridwidth=3;

    cardBD.add(titrePage,gbcPage);


    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    panelActions.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panelActions.add(buttonAdd,gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    panelActions.add(buttonUpdate,gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    panelActions.add(buttonDel,gbc);

    gbcPage.gridx=0;
    gbcPage.gridy=1;
    Border border = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK);
    Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);
    panelActions.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border,margin));
    panelActions.setBackground(Color.white);

    gbcPage.gridwidth=1;
    gbcPage.insets=new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    cardBD.add(panelActions,gbcPage);

    panelInfosRow.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(0,0,0,0);
    labelId.setText("ID");
    panelInfosRow.add(labelId,gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(2,0,0,0);
    textId.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));
    panelInfosRow.add(textId,gbc);


    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(15,0,0,0);
    panelInfosRow.add(label1,gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(2,0,0,0);
    text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
    panelInfosRow.add(text1,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.insets=new Insets(2,0,0,0);
    combo.setVisible(false);
    panelInfosRow.add(combo,gbc);

    .....

    gbcPage.gridx=1;
    gbcPage.gridy=1;
    gbcPage.gridwidth=1;
    gbcPage.insets=new Insets(10,20,0,0);
    cardBD.add(panelInfosRow,gbcPage);

    panelProd.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    Dimension dim = new Dimension(400,350);
    tableProd.setSize(dim);
    tableProd.setPreferredSize(dim);
    tableProd.setMinimumSize(dim);
    tableProd.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    tableProd.setModel(modeleDatas);
 tableProd.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(dim);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    panelProd.add(labelProd, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    JScrollPane scrollTab=new JScrollPane(tableProd);    
    scrollTab.setPreferredSize(dim);

    panelProd.add(scrollTab, gbc);

    gbcPage.gridx=2;
    gbcPage.gridy=1;
    gbcPage.gridwidth=1;
    cardBD.add(panelProd,gbcPage);


    logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/logo_station_phone2.png"));

    cardHome.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    cardHome.add(logo,gbc);
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    cardHome.add(new JLabel("Choix point de vente "),gbc);
    gbc.insets = new Insets(2,0,0,0);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
     MagasinDAO magasinBDD = new MagasinDAO(daoFactory);
     Object[][] magasins = magasinBDD.trouverMagasins();


     choix_magasin.addItem(new ObjectIdValue(-1, ""));
     if(prefs.getLong("id_point",-1)==-1)
         choix_magasin.setSelectedIndex(0);

     for(int i= 0 ; i<magasins.length;i++){
         choix_magasin.addItem(new ObjectIdValue((long) magasins[i][0], (String) magasins[i][1]));
         if(prefs.getLong("id_point",-1)==(long) magasins[i][0])
             choix_magasin.setSelectedIndex(i+1);
     }



    choix_magasin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           prefs.putLong("id_point", ((ObjectIdValue)choix_magasin.getSelectedItem()).getId());
        }
    });
    cardHome.add(choix_magasin,gbc);

    cardVente.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth=2;
    cardVente.add(labelVente, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth=2;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(8,0,0,0);
    listModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    liste_prod_vente.setModel(listModel);
    cardVente.add(liste_prod_vente, gbc);


    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(8,0,0,0);
    gbc.gridwidth=2;
    cardVente.add(label_vente_client,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(2,0,0,0);
    gbc.gridwidth=2;
    cardVente.add(liste_client,gbc);





    panels.add(cardHome,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panels.add(cardBD,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panels.add(cardVente, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    cardHome.setVisible(true);
    cardBD.setVisible(false);
    cardBD.setVisible(false);
```

So, i don't know what is the problem so weird. I'm waiting for solutions thanks.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly configure the layout manager of the **parent container** that holds the `JScrollPane` (which in turn holds your `JTable`).
From line

```
panelProd.add(scrollTab, gbc);
```

in your first code snippet, I guess the parent container is `panelProd` and its layout manager is a `GridBagLayout`. Thus you need to properly configure the `GridBagConstraints` instance (which I guess is `gbc`) associated to your scroll pane. You probably need something like

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraint.BOTH;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
panelProd.add(scrollTab, gbc);
```

Do not set preferred sizes for your scroll pane and your table in this case!!

However, without knowing the rest of the code that populates `panelProd` it is impossible to tell for sure.

*Edit to reflect additional source code in original question:*

Replace the code from line

```
panelProd.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

to line

```
cardBD.add(panelProd,gbcPage);
```

with

```
JPanel panelProd = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
tableProd.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
tableProd.setModel(modeleDatas);
panelProd.add(labelProd, BorderLayout.NORTH);

JScrollPane scrollTab=new JScrollPane(tableProd);    
panelProd.add(scrollTab, BorderLayout.CENTER);

int oldFill = gbcPage.fill;
double oldWeightX = gbcPage.weightx;
double oldWeightY = gbcPage.weighty;

gbcPage.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbcPage.gridx=2;
gbcPage.gridy=1;
gbcPage.gridwidth=1;
gbcPage.weightx=1;
gbcPage.weighty=1;
cardBD.add(panelProd,gbcPage);

gbc.fill = oldFill;
gbc.weightx = oldWeightX;
gbc.weighty = oldWeightY;
```

`GridBagLayout` is not necessary for simple arrangements like your `prodPanel` (`BorderLayout` is sufficient and much simpler to use in this case).

Comment: i just did this to Jpanel panelProd : panelProd.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

Comment: @cilies38 And how do you configure `gbc` for the left and middle column?

Comment: GridBagConstraints gbcPage = new GridBagConstraints();
        cardBD.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());                   
       gbcPage.gridwidth=1;
        gbcPage.insets=new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        cardBD.add(panelActions,gbcPage);////////////////        gbcPage.gridx=1;
        gbcPage.gridy=1;
        gbcPage.gridwidth=1;
        gbcPage.insets=new Insets(10,20,0,0);
        cardBD.add(panelInfosRow,gbcPage);

Comment: @cilies38 That code is not related to `panelProd`. I think you should edit your original answer to contain all of your UI code.
And please, please do **not** post unformatted code.

Comment: i edited the question and added ui code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @cilies38 I have edited my answer in response to the additional code.

Comment: it works with the correct config of the layout manager. Thanks. just the JTextField are remaing too small unitl i resize the window to full height. But i will search the solution myself.